# Exclude one class file in gradle Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, facebook-sdk-4.x

In my projects, I need to import third party jar file and Facebook SDK.

```
compile files('libs/SkinSDK.jar')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.0'
```

Both include same `BundleJSONConverter` class. So, I cannot do generate signed APK. It always shows duplicate entry com/facebook/internal/BundleJSONConverter.

So, I want to exclude in Facebook or SkinSDK.jar. I tried like

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.facebook.internal', module: 'BundleJSONConverter'
}
```

It's not working and showing same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `exclude` method of the configuration closure for a dependency excludes transitive dependencies. So, if your module dependency depends on other modules, you can exclude them from your build. You can check out the transitive dependencies of the `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.0'` module on its [Maven repository info page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk/4.14.0).

If the `BundleJSONConverter` class exists in a transitive dependency, you can exclude the specific module in the same way you are trying now. Just specify the `group`, the `module` and the `version`, like you do for dependencies.

If you just want to exclude one class for a dependency jar, take a look at the [*jar jar links*](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar) tool and its Gradle plugin. It allows you to alter included jars, e.g. to change packages or remove classes.

The following [(shortened) example](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar/blob/master/jarjar-gradle/example/build.gradle#L86) shows the usage of the plugin and some methods to alter the dependency jar:

```
compile jarjar.repackage {
    from 'org.apache.hive:hive-exec:0.13.0.2.1.5.0-695'

    archiveBypass "commons*.jar"
    archiveExclude "slf4j*.jar"

    classDelete "org.apache.thrift.**"
    classRename 'org.json.**', 'org.anarres.hive.json.@1'
}
```

Comment: Could not get unknown property jarjar I am getting. What to do?

Comment: @Nallamachu You need to include the *jar jar links* plugin. Sadly, it is not available via the Gradle Plugin Portal, so you cannot just use the `plugins` closure. Check out this full [example `build.gradle`](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar/blob/master/jarjar-gradle/example/build.gradle) instead.

Comment: Can we use this library for jar files in libs folder? If yes, then what should be the value for from in the closure, say the jar file is libs/my-sample.jar?

Answer (score 2):

Bumped into similar situation. This is what I did, not elegant as I hoped, but it works:

1. Rename the jar file (SkinSDK.jar in your case): .zip instead of .jar
2. Go "inside" the zip file (I'm using DoubleCommander, there are many other utilities for that), or extract it to a temporary folder.
3. Delete the duplicate class that causes the problem. Go "outside" the zip file.
4. Rename (or re-pack) the file from .zip to .jar . Compile.

Hope it works...

Comment: To shorten this procedure: There is no need to rename or repack the archive. Any `jar` file is a `zip` file, you should be able to open it with various tools (e.g. 7-zip).

Comment: Also, please document this `jar` file change! Otherwise you will run into problems when updating the external library.

Comment: Note that the question was about doing it with gradle and not manually

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with duplicated classes after importing a jar. In my case, the conflict was between a class in that jar and a class in my own project.
Below I share the solution you can use to discard classes that you have available in your own source tree, assuming the one in the jar is the right one to use:

```
android {
   sourceSets {
     main {
       java {
            filter.excludes = [
                    "com/package/Duplicated.java",                      
            ]
       }
     }
   }
}
```