# Android : [Adding Custom framework.jar file] duplicate entry for ConnectTimeoutException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to integrate custom framework.jar in my code and setting the priority of this new framework.jar file over android provided jar file, but while compiling the code I am getting below error :

Execution failed for task ':nuswypedev:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:org/apache/http/conn/ConnectTimeoutException.class

How to solve this issue?

Comment: please post `build.gradle` code

Comment: In my module build.gradle, I added framework.jar scope as provided and modified app.iml file by moving the <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 27 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" /> to last, so that custom framework.jar file is having priority.

Comment: try this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913406/exclude-one-class-file-in-gradle-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your program jars or library jars contain multiple definitions of the listed classes.

You can check the dependencies by

```
./gradlew app:dependencies | grep "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore"
```

After you found the duplication, you can use reference below "exclude group" syntax to exclude one of them

**Example**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('log4j:log4j:1.2.15') {
        exclude group: 'javax.jms', module: 'jms'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.jdmk', module: 'jmxtools'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.jmx', module: 'jmxri'
    }
}
```

Comment: I have following jar file "framework.jar" and I am adding it as :

compile files('libs/framework.jar')

How to exclude the ConnectTimeOutException class?

Comment: @SHUBHAMPRAKASH `compile files('libs/framework.jar') {exclude group: 'com.domain', module: 'libraryName'} ` but before that you should know which jar contains that 'ConnectTimeOutException'